# Em font size is adding margin to the top of my h1?

Tags: css, yui, reset, ems

I started using a CSS reset (YUI) for the first time with my personal site at http://www.tommaxwell.me, and it has helped a lot with cross-browser compatibility. However, in webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari), the ems font size seems to be adding margin to the top of the h1. When I remove the em, it falls back the default size and doesn't have the margin on the top. In Opera and Firefox that margin isn't there. What should I do?

Comment: In chrome as well as firefox it is coming fine.

Comment: if you try a good css reset like normalize or html5 boilerplate reset, you won't have this problem. You can also inspect the h1 with the developer tools from Safari (or chrome) and see where the margin-top comes from.

Comment: Which margin are you referring to? I don’t see any substantial difference between Firefox and Chrome renderings.

Comment: @VladNicula - I'll check 'em out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

kindly try to use px instead or try this

```
.webkit h1{margin:0px}
```

thanks hope it would help
..

Comment: Did you try it? Is there a reason to suspect that `0px` has an effect different from that of `0`? By the specifications, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If you Inspect h1 Element then you will see that all margins are 0 for h1 tag.

But height varies for h1 tag in all browsers and this is due to their rendering engine. And that variation maybe creating illusion for you about margin

Comment: Fair enough, but the difference is pretty noticeable. There has to be a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean as they look same to me across most browsers, but I can't see you setting a line-height anywhere, as a suggestion it may be worth fiddling with the line-height to see if the space is coming from there?

```
h1 {
    line-height: 1.0em;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'd suspect line-height is the culprit too. But with line-height you can remove the measurement units, it can be completely unit-less, as in line-height: 1;

Comment: I'll try it. On Safari and Chrome for Mac I see extra space above the h1, and I've tested it on two Macs.